# Django admin not working?

Tags: python, django

I just setup a new server on Digital Ocean. Updated Django to 1.11, uploaded my project, ran `collectstatic` and I've made sure my settings match another project I have (which is live and works 100%). However, my static doesn't collect correctly into my static folder (which I have it set to do), any media I upload wont display, and the admin still has the all design from before I updated it to 1.11... Any thoughts? settings code below..

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',

    'listings',
    'stats',
    'users',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

)
```

...

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/static/',
]


#MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Also here's a picture of my file structure: Note that admin did not collect in static

[image]

Comment: How are you serving the static files? With `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: I am using Nginx

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
```

I think `STATIC_ROOT` should be your static direcory in the deployment directory, e.g. `/var/www/mysite/static`.

and if that does not work, please add what `collectstatic` command returns (on the shell) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is given STATIC and STATIC_ROOT the same directory.Create a new folder named static_store for STATIC and static_cdn for STATIC_ROOT.Hope it works well!